# MultipleObjectsReturned at /checkout/ get() returned more than one Order -- it returned 2

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hi I'm trying to develop an e-commerce website using Django. I have two models and views on separate folders, one is an order model and view, another is the checkout model and view. The order view creates a new order everytime an item is added to the cart. And the checkout view creates a new billing address. I want to associate the billing address that is created to the order when the checkout form is submitted. But for some reason, it's not happening. It throws an error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /checkout/
get() returned more than one Order -- it returned 2!
```

What is the problem?

My orders.models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from shopping_cart.models import Cart
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from accounts2.models import BillingAddress


STATUS_CHOICES = (
       ("Started", "Started"),
       ("Abandoned", "Abandoned"),
       ("Finished", "Finished"),
   )

User = get_user_model()

class Order(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
   order_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='ABC',  unique=True)
   cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="Started")
   sub_total = models.DecimalField(default=10.99, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
   tax_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
   final_total = models.DecimalField(default=10.99, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
   billing_address = models.ForeignKey(BillingAddress, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank= True, null=True)
```

My orders.views.py:

```
@login_required
def order(request):
   try:
       the_id = request.session['cart_id']
       cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
   except:
       the_id = None
       return redirect(reverse("myshop-home"))

   try:
       new_order = Order.objects.get(cart=cart)
   except Order.DoesNotExist:
       new_order = Order(cart=cart)
       new_order.cart = cart
       new_order.user = request.user
       new_order.order_id = id_generator()
       new_order.save()
   except:
       return redirect(reverse("cart"))


   if new_order.status == "Finished":
       #cart.delete()
       del request.session['cart_id']
       del request.session['items_total']
       return redirect(reverse("cart"))


   context = {"address_form": address_form, "cart": cart}
   template = "orders/checkout.html"
   return render(request, template, context)
```

My accounts.models.py:

```
class BillingAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apartment_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField(multiple=False)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Billing Addresses"
```

My accounts.views.py:

```
class CheckoutView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        the_id = self.request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
        form = CheckoutForm()
        context = {"form": form, "cart": cart}
        return render(self.request, "orders/checkout.html", context)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user = self.request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                street_address = form.cleaned_data.get('street_address')
                apartment_address = form.cleaned_data.get('apartment_address')
                country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
                zip = form.cleaned_data.get('zip')
                # same_shipping_address = form.cleaned_data.get('same_billing_address')
                # save_info = form.cleaned_data.get('save_info')
                payment_option = form.cleaned_data.get('payment_option')
                billing_address = BillingAddress(
                        user = self.request.user,
                        street_address = street_address,
                        apartment_address = apartment_address,
                        country = country,
                        zip = zip
                    )
                billing_address.save()
                order.billing_address = billing_address
                order.save()
                return redirect('checkout')
            messages.warning(self.request, "Failed checkout")
            return redirect('checkout')

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect('/')
```

Comment: it happens because `Order.objects.get()` returns multiple objects, but `get` was designed to retrieve a single object

Comment: What can I do to fix it sir?

Comment: Is there anyway to associate them and solve the problem?

Comment: use `filter` instead, if you want to retrieve multiple objects

Comment: I want to get the order that is created exactly now by the user

Comment: you can get the last object. `Order.objects.filter(user=user).last()`

Comment: Unrelated, by all mean, DO NOT USE BARE EXCEPT CLAUSES. Alway only catch the exact errors you're expecting and can properly handle (silencing an error and redirecting to another url is NOT proper error handling).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Order.objects.filter(user=user).last()` to get the newest row or try to remember order's id when creating an order and filter with `Order.objects.get(id=id)`